# Warning: FrontEnd crash with `Graphics@InfiniteLine` for unknown symbolic coordinates

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.0.1**
`InfiniteLine` is new in 10.0.

> [CASE:3840702] From your description, I gather you are noticing an unexpected crash
>   while trying to evaluate Graphics@InfiniteLine@{{0,0},x} .
>
> I tested and confirmed your issue and have passed it along to our
>   developers for further diagnosis. -- WRI

---

I reported this to WRI:

This works fine:

```
Graphics@InfiniteLine@{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

This crashes the Front End.
**WARNING:** A Front End crash results in losing all unsaved work!

```
Graphics@InfiniteLine@{{0, 0}, x}
```

---

Does this happen on everyone's system or is it specific to mine?

Comment: Confirmed on Win10 V11.0.1

Comment: Crashes all (FE+Kernel) on OSX 10.11 and MMA v 11.0.1. Actually it crashes whatever `x` is (integer, real, ...).

Comment: @SquareOne Really? It does not crash on my system if x is defined to say (1,1). It only crashes when it is undefined, ie. symbolic I thought.

Comment: @masterxilo If you replace `x` with  something which is NOT at least a pair of two parameters `{_,_}`, yes it crashes it all for me. For example replace `x` with `1` or `16.2` or `{12}` or any string like : `Graphics@InfiniteLine@{{0, 0}, "hello"}`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in 11.1 (windows). No crash. Just an error message

```
$Version

11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)

Graphics@InfiniteLine@{{0, 0}, x}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]